# Bootstrap DropDown needs attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Bootstrap dropdown:

Code:

```
<li><a  href="#">sometext</a></li>
```

it works great but how can i add the attribute value ?
like this: 
code:

```
<option value=value>text</option>
```

So how can i add the attribute value ?

Comment: they removed it:  <li><a  href="#">text</a> </li>

Comment: What attribute? and to what element?. The first is an `<a>` tag and the second is an `<option>` tag associated with a `<select>`

Comment: `$('option').attr('value','value').text('text')` ??

Comment: i mean i need something like that: <li><a value=1 href="#">sometext</a></li> in bootstrap drop dwon we have only <li> not option

Comment: The `<a>` tag does not have a `value` attribute ([refer docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)). What is it your trying do do?

Comment: You are trying to create a bootstrap menu from a select element? If I'm right have a look at this: [http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: i want to have a dropdwon with text and value and show the text and the value will submited to the server. iam using this here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: The create a dropdown using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` and apply the `.selectpicker();` to it.

Comment: but why the bootstrap dropdwon doesnt have the attribute value????

Comment: Because bootstrap use HTML and in the HTML spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), `value` is not a valid attribute for a `a` element. You can't just add the attribute you want, you have to follow the spec, or prefix your attribute name with `data-` (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in attributes by using `data-` in such a manner:

```
<li><a data-myAttribute="myValue" href="#">sometext</a></li>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Then you can use JQuery to get the value in such a way:

```
var myValue = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute");
```

Nice thing about this is you can stack in as many attributes as you want, ie:

```
<li><a data-AttA="A" data-AttB="B" data-AttC="C" data-Foo="bar" href="#">sometext</a></li>
```